# How do I restrict a section of form that only a certain group can edit?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

How do I restrict a section of a form that only a certain group can edit? I created the group with these fields:

Group type: Access Control List only
Category: ACL Control, Database ACL Group

I tried these steps from this link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_RESTRICTING_ACCESS_TO_A_SECTION.html

1. Highlight the text, fields, and other design elements on a form that make up the section.
2. Choose Create - Section - Controlled Access.

But when I highlighted the section of the form that I want to restrict, I cannot select the Controlled Access and is grayed out.
[image: Controlled Access]

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing what you've highlighted for your section.

Comment: You need to expand or reduce your selection. You have either to much or to less selected...

Comment: I tried both still cant select. I can only select the Controlled Access if I didn't highlight any. How does it work if nothing? Like down to bottom will be restricted? Im using domino designer 8.0 btw. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create a controlled access section with a nested standard section inside it?

Comment: Hi Richard, Im trying to create a controlled access on a certain section of a form which is in the middle part.

Comment: That's the error: You dont "change" a normal section to a controlled section. First REMOVE the section (NOT THE CONTENT), then select the content again and create a controlled section.